# Estoy haciendo que en una datatable, haya en enlace en un registro que cuando clickes se te abra un modal para poder modificarlo

Tags: javascript, php, sql, datatables, modal

Tengo varias partes de código, en principio voy a poner ciertas partes que me parecen a mi mas importantes, si se necesitan más partes no dudéis en pedirlas, muchas gracias de antemano.
Este es el archivo panel_administracion.php donde se crea la datatable, y en concreto estas líneas son las que quiero que se me abra el modal.

```
<?php
echo "<td><a id='ajax-personales$i' data-url='edita_alumno.php?id=$fila_matriculas[2]&matricula=$fila_matriculas[0]' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#myModal'>$nombre_completo_alumno</a></td>";
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Contenido del modal -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tiene un js que el siguiente

```
$('a[data-bs-toggle="modal"]').click(function() {
var url = $(this).data('url');
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#modal-content').html(response);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }
});
});
```

El modal al que hace referencia, se encuentra en edita_alumno.php y tiene el siguiente código

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="caption font-dark">
            <i class="fa fa-settings font-dark" area-hidden='true'></i>

            <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">Edición de datos personales</span>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="portlet box blue" name="div_cobros" id="div_cobros">
                                    <div class="portlet-title">
                                        <div class="caption" style="font-size: large; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 3%;"> <?php echo ($fila_alumno[1]).", ".($fila_alumno[2]); ?>
                                            <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> </div>
                                    
                                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">                  
                    <form action="./guardar_datos_personales.php" name="submit_form" method="POST" role="form"> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                        <label class="control-label">Apellidos
                                        <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo ($fila_alumno[1]); ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Nombre
                                        <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="<?php echo ($fila_alumno[2]); ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr ></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                        <label class="control-label">DNI
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                          <input maxlength="9" required type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[3]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Sexo
                                        <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <select required class="form-control" name='genero'>
                                                <?php

                                                    switch ($fila_alumno[16]) {
                                                        case 0:
                                                            echo '<option value="0" selected>-</option>
                                                                <option value="1">Hombre</option>
                                                                <option value="2">Mujer</option>';
                                                        break;
                                                        case 1:
                                                            echo '<option value="0">-</option>
                                                                <option value="1" selected>Hombre</option>
                                                                <option value="2">Mujer</option>';
                                                        break;
                                                        case 2:
                                                            echo '<option value="0">-</option>
                                                                <option value="1">Hombre</option>
                                                                <option value="2" selected>Mujer</option>';
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                ?>
                                                
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                        <label class="control-label">Teléfono móvil
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input maxlength="9" required type="text" class="form-control" name="movil" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[13]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Fecha de nacimiento
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_nacimiento" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[6]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                    <label class="control-label">Email
                                        <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="submit_form_email" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[7]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                    <label class="control-label">Dirección
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="address" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[8]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                    <label class="control-label">Población
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="city" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[9]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Provincia<span class="required"></span></label>
                                        <div>
                                            <select required name="provincia" id="country_list" class="form-control">
                                            <?php
                                                $busca_provincias="SELECT * FROM provincias";
                                                $result_provincias=mysqli_query($conexion, $busca_provincias);
                                                while ($fila_provincias=mysqli_fetch_row($result_provincias)){
                                                    $selected="";
                                                    if ($fila_provincias[0]==$fila_alumno[11]){
                                                        $selected="SELECTED";
                                                    }
                                                    echo "<option value=".($fila_provincias[0])." $selected>".($fila_provincias[1])."</option>";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                    <label class="control-label">Código Postal
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input maxlength="5" required type="text" class="form-control" name="cp" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[10]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                    <label class="control-label">Titula
                                            <span class="required"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <select required class="form-control" name='titula'>
                                                <?php

                                                    switch ($fila_iban[1]) {
                                                        case 0:
                                                            echo '<option value="0" selected>No</option>
                                                                <option value="1">Si</option>';
                                                        break;
                                                        case 1:
                                                            echo '<option value="0">No</option>
                                                                <option value="1" selected>Si</option>';
                                                        break;
                                                    }

                                                ?>
                                                
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <!-- <div class= "col-md-4"></div> -->
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                    <label class="control-label">Email Safa
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_safa" id="submit_form_email" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[15]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Teléfono fijo
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input maxlength="9" type="text" class="form-control" name="fijo" value="<?php echo $fila_alumno[14]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <!-- <div class= "col-md-4"></div> -->
                            <div class="form-group two-fields">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="col-4" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                        <label class="control-label">IBAN
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fomr_iban" id="submit_form_iban" value="<?php echo $fila_iban[0]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-4">
                                        <label class="control-label">Nota Media
                                        </label>
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="number" max='10' min='0' class="form-control" name="nota_media" value="<?php echo $fila_iban[2]; ?>"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                               
                            <label class="control-label">Observaciones</label>
                                        <div>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="observaciones1"><?php echo $fila_alumno[12]; ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"><hr></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_alumno" value="<?php echo $id_alumno; ?>">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_matricula" value="<?php echo $id_matricula; ?>">

                            <br><br>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success hover-scale">Guardar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger hover-scale"><a style="color:black;"href="panel_administracion.php">Cancelar</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Muchas por haber leído mi pregunta y si es posible intentar ayudarme.

Comment: Se te olvido poner la poner la pregunta. Utiliza el botón [edit] para agregarla.